# More complicated range generation

Tags: php

Producing a range with PHP is easy when the range is something like 1 to 100 or A to Z. But I need to be able to produce ranges like 101A to 101Z or A1 to A100.

I thought that maybe PHP has a function to compare two strings, strip what's common between them and return the rest to form the range boundaries. However I can not find such a function. How would I achieve this?

EDIT: I don't have control over the format, I can only set the guidelines. The end user determines the pattern by entering something like `A1-A100` into an input field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my own, not so elegant solution. It works with the following logic:

Range boundaries have two parts, of which the other is digit and the other non-digit, such as `A1` or `1A`. One-part string work too, such as `A` or `1`. I did not test with strings such as `A1B` where there are more than two parts. The script probably fails there.

```
$s1 = '101A';
$s2 = '101Z';

$s1_d = preg_split('/\d+/', $s1);
$s1_D = preg_split('/\D+/', $s1);
$s2_d = preg_split('/\d+/', $s2);
$s2_D = preg_split('/\D+/', $s2);

if($s1_d[0] == '') $s1_d[0] = $s1_D[0];
else $s1_d[1] = $s1_D[1];
$s1 = $s1_d;

if($s2_d[0] == '') $s2_d[0] = $s2_D[0];
else $s2_d[1] = $s2_D[1];
$s2 = $s2_d;

$prefix = false;
$postfix = false;

if($s1[0] == $s2[1]) die(); // Can't do it.

if($s1[0] == $s2[0]) {
    $prefix = $s1[0];
    $start = $s1[1];
    $end = $s2[1];
}
else {
    $postfix = $s1[1];
    $start = $s1[0];
    $end = $s2[0];
}    

$range = range($start, $end);
foreach($range as &$r) {
    $r = $prefix . $r . $postfix;
}

var_dump($range);
```

Answer (score 0):

`101A` to `101Z` is like `"101" + range("A", "Z")`

and

`A1` to `A100` is like `"A" + range(1, 100)`

If you're looking for `A1` to `Z100` that's when things get a bit more complicated.
You can look at the way functions like base converters work, like `dechex` and `base64_encode`

If you're converting from the decimal system to your own notation you can do thing kind of conversion.

```
1 => A1
2 => A2
101 => B1
102 => B2
2601? => Z1
2700? => Z100
```

This just describes the outline. If you want code you'll have to make your question more clear.

---

Arbitrary ranges is .. very hard. I don't know of a solution. `A1-A100` has a clear solution, but what about `A1-100Z`, how do you even begin? What about `small-large` or `Boston-New York`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with:

```
function rangeFix($from, $to, $prefix = null, $suffix = null) {
    return array_map(function($item) use ($prefix, $suffix){
        return $prefix . $item . $suffix;
    }, range($from, $to));
}

rangeFix(0, 10, 'A', 'Z');
```

Output:

```
array (size=11)
  0 => string 'A0Z' (length=3)
  1 => string 'A1Z' (length=3)
  2 => string 'A2Z' (length=3)
  3 => string 'A3Z' (length=3)
  4 => string 'A4Z' (length=3)
  5 => string 'A5Z' (length=3)
  6 => string 'A6Z' (length=3)
  7 => string 'A7Z' (length=3)
  8 => string 'A8Z' (length=3)
  9 => string 'A9Z' (length=3)
  10 => string 'A10Z' (length=4)
```

or:

```
rangeFix('A', 'Z', 101);
```

Output:

```
array (size=26)
  0 => string '101A' (length=4)
  1 => string '101B' (length=4)
  2 => string '101C' (length=4)
  3 => string '101D' (length=4)
  4 => string '101E' (length=4)
  5 => string '101F' (length=4)
  6 => string '101G' (length=4)
  7 => string '101H' (length=4)
  8 => string '101I' (length=4)
  9 => string '101J' (length=4)
  10 => string '101K' (length=4)
  11 => string '101L' (length=4)
  12 => string '101M' (length=4)
  13 => string '101N' (length=4)
  14 => string '101O' (length=4)
  15 => string '101P' (length=4)
  16 => string '101Q' (length=4)
  17 => string '101R' (length=4)
  18 => string '101S' (length=4)
  19 => string '101T' (length=4)
  20 => string '101U' (length=4)
  21 => string '101V' (length=4)
  22 => string '101W' (length=4)
  23 => string '101X' (length=4)
  24 => string '101Y' (length=4)
  25 => string '101Z' (length=4)
```